# ¿Hacer este círculo específico en html/css?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado haciéndolo en CSS así:

```
     .circle{
        background-color: white;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        border-radius: 50%;

    }
```

y me da un círculo completo pero sólo quiero que se vea la línea blanca ya que lo de dentro es de la imagen de fondo, en otros posts que he encontrado sólo dicen un círculo como el que he dicho antes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para permitir ver el fondo tendrías que ponerle al `<div>` del círculo un `background-color: transparent` y para el borde blanco del círculo tienes que darle estilos al borde, que es lo que estás redondeando con `border-radius: 50%;`.

```css
.fondo {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.circulo {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="fondo">
  <div class="circulo">
  
  </div>
</div>
```